# Selec2: combining ajax remote data with templateSelection

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2-4

I want to load an specific data into select2 while set to use remote data. I have a page with a select2 element that user can change, but if they accessed the page using an id option on the url, I try to pre-load that item into the select2.

The problem is that the returned data from server is an object that is used to format selection based on. Both on loading and on changing the value, it mess up the formatting. Here's the code looks like so far in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x82hvzy9/13/).

```
var formatGroup = function(item) { return item.text; };
var formatGroupSelection = function(item) { 
    var markup = '<i class="fa fa-user'+
        ((item.type==1)?'':'s')+
    '"></i>&nbsp;'+
        (item.name || item.text)+
    '<span style="float: right; margin-right: 20px">'+
        (item.system || 'general')+
    '</span>';
  return markup;
};

var sampleData = [
{ id: 1, name: 'grp1', system: 'sys1', type: 1 },
{ id: 2, name: 'grp2', system: 'sys1', type: 2 },
{ id: 3, name: 'grp3', system: 'sys2', type: 1 },
{ id: 4, name: 'grp4', system: 'sys2', type: 2 }
];

var $select = jQuery('#group_edit');
$select.select2({
    ajax: {
    url: "/url/to/resource",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term,
        page: params.page,
        all: true,
        strict: !(jQuery('#inclusive').get()[0].checked)
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  placeholder: 'select a group',
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%',
  templateResult: formatGroup,
  templateSelection: formatGroupSelection
});

if (grpid != null) {
  var $option = jQuery('<option selected>Loading...</option>').val(grpid);
  $select.append($option).trigger('change');

  jQuery.ajax({ // make the request for the selected data object
    url: "url/to/resource?id=" + grpid,
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'json'
  }).then(function (data) {
    grp = data;
    jQuery('#inclusive').get()[0].checked = true;
    $option.text(data.name).val(data.id);
    $option.removeData();
    $select.trigger('change');
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `formatGroupSelection` references `scope` but takes in `item`. You never said in your question what the problem is with the formatting, so that's my best guess.

Comment: @KevinBrown oops! sorry that's a typo. I tried changing names so it would be general. consider it scope, I edit it. The jsfiddle one is correct and working though. Thanks.